# the most problematic or loud person gets the most attention and quiet person is ignored

Tags: idiom-requests

What is the idiom in English where the loudest or most troublesome person gets all the attention, while those who are quiet are ignored?

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe, but I can't find the canonical target.

Comment: @DanBron Are you thinking of [this post?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332602/are-there-english-proverbs-that-warn-against-speaking-up-in-front-of-people/332603#332603)

Comment: @Cascabel No, that's somewhat the opposite of this question (though obviously related).

Comment: Related: [AmEng equivalent of “Shy kids get no sweets”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144414)

Answer (score 8):

[**The squeaky wheel gets the grease.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_squeaky_wheel_gets_the_grease)

> The squeaky wheel gets the grease is an American idiom used to convey the idea that the most noticeable (or loudest) problems are the ones most likely to get attention. It is alternately expressed as "The squeaky wheel gets the oil".[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_squeaky_wheel_gets_the_grease)

See also [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/squeaky-wheel-gets-the-grease).

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: If only you linked to an authoritative site.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Done. And come on ... it's not like it was urbandictionary. :-)